# Line Fill Symbol is not shown on legend in ArcGIS Server print service

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, legend, printing, print-templates

I choose Line fill symbol for my polygon layer. When I export map in ArcMap it is ok. But printing with print service this symbol is not shown in the legend.  I add a screenshot.

How can I solve this problem?

I use:

ARCGIS SERVER 10.5.1 (Linux)

Template is desinged in ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The image links are broken but when sharing the print service make sure the legend is enabled. It's a random check box hidden somewhere when sharing the service